# Error en Post de PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, formularios

Estoy haciendo el proyecto final acerca de formularios en mi materia de programación Web, pero al momento de presionar el boton de registrar me muestra un error que dice: Cannot POST /registro.php

Aqui mi codigo HTML

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
    body {
        color: darkblue;
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(125,185,232,1) 71%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 99%); 
        


        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='lightblue', endColorstr='lightblue',GradientType=0 );
        font-family: "Century Gothic";
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 1.6;
}
    
    .form-input {
 display: block;
 width: 200px;
 height: 15px;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 color: #000;
 border: 1px solid #999;
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
 -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
 transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
 behavior: url(PIE.htc);
 font-family: "Century Gothic";
 font-size: 14px;
 padding-top: 5px;
 padding-right: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
 padding-left: 10px;
}
</style>
<title></title>
</head>

<body>
<div align='center'>
  <form action="registro.php" method="POST">
  <h2><em>Formulario de Registro</em></h2>  
     <p>
      <label for="Id_Pro"> <span>Id Proyecto</span></label>
      <input type="number" name="Id_Pro" class="form-input" required/>  
         
      <label for="nombre">Nombre <span><em>(requerido)</em></span></label>
      <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-input" required/>   
      
      <label for="departamento"> <span>Departamento</span></label>
      <input type="text" name="departamento" class="form-input" required/>  
         
      <label for="encargado"> <span>Encargado</span></label>
      <input type="text" name="encargado" class="form-input" required/>  
         
      <label for="costo"> <span>Costo</span></label>
      <input type="number" name="costo" class="form-input" required/>
         
     <center> <input class="form-btn" name="submit" type="submit" value="Registrar" /></center>
    </p>
  </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Aqui mi codigo PHP

```html
<?php
$db_host="localhost";
$db_user="root";
$db_password="";
$db_name="proyectos";
$db_table_name="proyecto";
   $db_connection = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_password);

if (!$db_connection) {
 die('No se ha podido conectar a la base de datos');
}
$subs_Id_Pro = utf8_decode($_POST['Id_Pro']);
$subs_nombre = utf8_decode($_POST['nombre']);
$subs_departamento = utf8_decode($_POST['departamento']);
$subs_encargado = utf8_decode($_POST['encargado']);
$subs_costo = utf8_decode($_POST['costo']);

$resultado=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$db_table_name." WHERE Id_Pro = ".$subs_Id_Pro." and Nombre= '".$subs_nombre."'", $db_connection);

if (mysql_num_rows($resultado)>0)
{

header('Location: Fail.html');

} else {
 
 $insert_value = 'INSERT INTO `' . $db_name . '`.`'.$db_table_name.'` (`Id_Pro` , `Nombre` , `Departamento` , `Encargado` , `Costo` ,) VALUES ("' . $subs_Id_Pro . '", "' . $subs_nombre . '", "' . $subs_departamento . ', "' . $subs_encargado . ', "' . $subs_costo . '")';

mysql_select_db($db_name, $db_connection);
$retry_value = mysql_query($insert_value, $db_connection);

if (!$retry_value) {
   die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
 
header('Location: Success.html');

}

mysql_close($db_connection);

  
?>
```

Comment: la ruta donde esta el archivo `registro.php` es la misma donde tienes el archivo que contiene el formulario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En primer lugar decirte que yo también soy estudiante, por lo que espero poder resolverte la duda. En principio, el error que te da parece ser por la dirección que introduces en el `action="registro.php"`, asegúrate que introduces correctamente la ruta. Por otra parte, la extensión `mysql` ya casi no se utiliza, creo que ya no se va a dar soporte. Deberías utilizar `MySQLi`.

```
<?php
$db_host="localhost";
$db_user="root";
$db_password="";
$db_name="proyectos";
$db_table_name="proyecto";

$db_connection = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name);
if (!$db_connection) {
    die('No se ha podido conectar a la base de datos');
}

$subs_Id_Pro = utf8_decode($_POST['Id_Pro']);
$subs_nombre = utf8_decode($_POST['nombre']);
$subs_departamento = utf8_decode($_POST['departamento']);
$subs_encargado = utf8_decode($_POST['encargado']);
$subs_costo = utf8_decode($_POST['costo']);


$resultado = $db_connection->query("SELECT * FROM $db_table_name WHERE Id_Pro = $subs_Id_Pro and Nombre = '$subs_nombre'");

if ($resultado->num_rows > 0 ) {
    header('Location: Fail.html');
} else {
  $insert_value=$db_connection->query("INSERT INTO $db_table_name(Id_Pro, 
  Nombre, Departamento, Encargado, Costo) VALUES($subs_Id_Pro, 
  '$subs_nombre', '$subs_departamento',                                              
  '$subs_encargado', $subs_costo)");

    if($insert_value){  
    header('Location: Success.html');
    }else{
      //CÓDIGO EN CASO QUE NO SE PUEDA HACER EL INSERT.
    }
}

$db_connection->close();
```

La parte de `utf8_decode();` yo la omitiría, ya que si tienes bien configurada la BBDD no tendrías que tener problema.

No sé cómo tendrás la BBDD pero me he creado una, intuyendo por los datos que pones los campos y a mí me ha funcionado perfectamente. Sobre todo eso, asegúrate de la ruta.

Espero haberte ayudado.
Un saludo.

Comment: las respuestas que incluyen código, no se añaden como imagen, sino como texto; dale en editar pega tu texto, seleccionalo y da clic en `{}`

Comment: Gracias shadow, cambiado.

Comment: El error era en la ruta, gracias por la respuesta